# How i can receive a notification in app of a new message of social networks

Tags: ios, objective-c

I develop a client for social networks. The question is how to receive a notification of a new message that appears? With API social networks do not communicate directly, via my server. Actually the question - how i could have received notification of a new message? I tried via push. It's normally? Who will offer other ways?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you recive notifications from two channels: your app API and push notifications. When something happens in your app (a new reply in one of your messages, a new private message) your server-side app should do two things:

1. Send a push notification to the users involved
2. Save notifications in database to notify the users when they open the app

If you do this, you notify all the users through a push notification (they will recive a message even if your app is not running) and then you also have the ability to sync the app to the new user data (that's the notifications saved in database) when they open the app.

For this, you need to have control about your server-side app.